# Multicast-Message within VLAN using IPv6 has no 802.1Q-field (VLAN) within Ethernet frame

Tags: ipv6, multicast, vlan, vsomeip

I want to know how multicast works in VLAN for the IPv6 address domain. **Can anybody tell me, whether the VLAN ID - by specification - is added to an Ethernet frame, when I send data to an IPv6 multicast address?**

[image: Missing VLAN field (802.1Q...) in the IPv6 ethernet frame for a multicast target address]

I have no formal education about networking. I work with a library (**vsomeip 3.3.8**) that uses socket communication within the SOME/IP context. I observed that for IPv4 multicast addresses, the VLAN field is added to the ethernet frame. For IPv6 it does NOT. So I wonder whether the library has a bug, or maybe my understanding of IPv6's behavior is wrong when it comes to multicasting.

In my understanding of VLAN, I expect the VLAN field to be set for all messages within the VLAN.

**Not visible**: in the above IPv6 Wireshark trace, the messages to unicast addresses (beef::1, beef::2) contain the expected VLAN field. So it shows me, that my machines are actually within the VLAN.
[image: IPv4 with VLAN field (802.1Q...) in ethernet frame for a multicast target address]

Comment: One thing is that the `2` in your `ff24` is an invalid flag. You can have `0`, `1`, `3`, or `7`.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware that "flags and scope" exist for IPv6 multicast addresses, but do not know them by hard. I changed it to valid values, the behavior is the same. No VLAN in IPv6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in the library vsomeip 3.3.8. It does not work with VLANs in this version.

Multicast does NOT change the behavior of VLAN in IPv6.